# Ubuntu 18.04 videos freezing locally and online

Tags: 18.04, video, freeze

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and the videos I play locally(in vlc) and online(youtube) freezes for about 2 seconds often. 
I have also dual booted windows 10 and in windows it plays normally.

Please note:- The audio plays without any freezing it's only the video that freezes.